# Can I access my Scala app's name and version (as set in SBT) from code?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-buildinfo

I am building an app with SBT (0.11.0) using a Scala build definition like so:

```
object MyAppBuild extends Build {

  import Dependencies._

  lazy val basicSettings = Seq[Setting[_]](
    organization  := "com.my",
    version       := "0.1",
    description   := "Blah",
    scalaVersion  := "2.9.1",
    scalacOptions := Seq("-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8"),
    resolvers     ++= Dependencies.resolutionRepos
  )

  lazy val myAppProject = Project("my-app-name", file("."))
    .settings(basicSettings: _*)
    [...]
```

I'm packaging a .jar at the end of the process.

My question is a simple one: is there a way of accessing the application's name ("my-app-name") and version ("0.1") programmatically from my Scala code? I don't want to repeat them in two places if I can help it.

Any guidance greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you packaging a jar?

Comment: Sorry yes - have clarified in my question, thanks Jean-Philippe

Comment: I think sbt saves the version in the jar's manifest, no?

Comment: I'm not sure Jean-Philippe - I've seen code like this: `val version = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/version"))).readLine()` but I haven't been able to get it working...

Comment: This is working now for me `val currentVersion: String = {
  IO.readLines(new File("VERSION")).head
}`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

### sbt-buildinfo

I just wrote [sbt-buildinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo).
After installing the plugin:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin).
  settings(
    buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion),
    buildInfoPackage := "foo"
  )
```

Edit: The above snippet has been updated to reflect more recent version of sbt-buildinfo.

It generates `foo.BuildInfo` object with any setting you want by customizing `buildInfoKeys`.

### Ad-hoc approach

<s>I've been meaning to make a plugin for this,</s> (I wrote it) but here's a quick script to generate a file:

```
sourceGenerators in Compile <+= (sourceManaged in Compile, version, name) map { (d, v, n) =>
  val file = d / "info.scala"
  IO.write(file, """package foo
    |object Info {
    |  val version = "%s"
    |  val name = "%s"
    |}
    |""".stripMargin.format(v, n))
  Seq(file)
}
```

You can get your version as `foo.Info.version`.

Comment: Thanks **Eugene** - how do I make this a part of my build process - where do I put the code?

Comment: Since you're using .scala build, stick it in a `Seq` and append it to `basicSettings` as `.settings(basicSettings ++ Seq(sourceGenerators in Compile <+= (...) map {...}): _*)`.

Comment: Thanks **Eugene** - that's working really well. SBT source generation is powerful stuff!

Comment: I tried adding this to `build.sbt` and not sure how I can access the `foo.BuildInfo` from my scala class? any suggestions

Answer (score 50):

Name and version are inserted into manifest. You can access them using java reflection from [Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html) class.

```
val p = getClass.getPackage
val name = p.getImplementationTitle
val version = p.getImplementationVersion
```

Comment: I upvoted this before realizing that it won't work in test tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also generate a dynamic config file, and read it from scala.

```
// generate config (to pass values from build.sbt to scala)
Compile / resourceGenerators += Def.task {
  val file = baseDirectory.value / "conf" / "generated.conf"
  val contents = "app.version=%s".format(version.value)
  IO.write(file, contents)
  Seq(file)
}.taskValue
```

When you run `sbt universal:packageBin` the file will be there.